# PHP Search between two points

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to deal with some XML in PHP.

I have code, such as this:

```
<?php 
$stream = fopen("xml","r");
?>
```

Where "xml" contains something such as this:

```
<name>name1</name>
<key>key1</key>
<name>name2</name>
<key>key2</key>
```

etc.

I'd like to create an array out of the contents of the `<key>` tags, something like where
 `keys[0] = "key1"`
and 
 `keys[1] = "key2"`

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much :)

Solution:

```
$xmlstr = fread($stream,filesize("xml-file"));
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $sxe->getName() . "\n";
foreach ($sxe->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->children();
}
```

Comment: Use a xml parser, please

Comment: Can you recommend one please @Rizier123?

Comment: Start simple, with [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class

Comment: ^ Very cool!, nice that you could figure it out yourself

Answer (score 1):

You should use DOM functions for this case. Let's suppose a well-formed XML document (xmltest.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
    <name>name1</name>
    <key>key1</key>
    <name>name2</name>
    <key>key2</key>
  </root>
```

This code loads the xml file into DOM document and gets all nodes with tag `key`;

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$dom->load('xmltest.xml');
$keys = $dom->getElementsByTagName('key');
for ($i = 0; $i < $keys->length; $i++) {
    echo $keys->item($i)->nodeValue . "</br>";
}
?>
```